# Why isn't the Component.isInitialized() method public?

Tags: wicket

This method is package-private (I only checked version 7.6.0), but I found it very hard building proper failsafes into more complex components without the ability of checking the initialization states of the internal components. If I could access that method publicly it would certainly do no harm (it's a read-only method). Yet I did not find any alternative way of checking if a component instance passed initialization phase.

Comment: Why do you need to know whether a component is initialized ? I personally never needed to know this in my apps. If you have a good reason then I guess we can make it public!

Comment: For me it was needed when building larger customizable compound components. Some of its methods are only legit to be called before the initialization phase, since they effect how the component's internal parts get configured, so calling them after initialization would be misleading without throwing an exception, since they would be silently ignored. Maybe this is not the only way to do that, but I found this approach very useful in complex cases since it hides the internal complexity nice and straitforward while providing its own meaningful API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the method is `public` in 8.x (https://github.com/apache/wicket/commit/d1710298c7e371f260299f732c58d0bf4d647161). So you have two options: 1) use Wicket 8.0.0-M4 or file a ticket to make it public in 7.x as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will migrate to 8.0 once its released.